# Correct way to have site-wide common properties in asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Short question: what's the proper way to have common, site-wide, properties that are:

1. Accessible in both `_layout.cshtml` and other views
2. Strongly typed, ie. Model.TextInUserLanguage

And at the same time still allows custom controllers to their own model?

**In other words, how to tell asp.net to:**

1. Use `CommonModel` with `_layout.cshtml` by default
2. When accessing a controller **C** that has its own model **M** / view **V**, apply model M to view V (while still respecting rule #1)

---

**Long story**

I created a sample asp.net MVC 4 webapp, which has the `HomeController` and `AccountController` by default

**HomeController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CommonModel Model = new CommonModel { PageTitle = "HomePage" };
        return View(Model);
    }
```

**BaseModel.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string PageTitle { get; set; }

    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**CommonModel.cs**

```
public class CommonModel: BaseModel
{
    public CommonModel()
    {
        AppName = Properties.Settings.Default.AppName;
        Author = Properties.Settings.Default.Author;
        MetaDescription = Properties.Settings.Default.MetaDescription;
    }
}
```

**_layout.cshtml**

```
@model K6.Models.BaseModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@Model.PageTitle - @Model.AppName</title>
    ...
```

---

**The problem is**, this approach:

1. Really feels hacky
2. I have to change every controller in my webapp so that they use this `CommonModel` in order to make `_layout.cshtml` recognize my custom properties, but at the same time this requires significant work in order to make things work when dealing HTTP Posts, showing lists, etc...

There must be other way to do this. I'm new to asp.net MVC, so what's the best way to do this about having to use `ViewBag`?

Comment: You can always just use `@Html.Action()` in your layout to call a controller method that returns a partial view of the html you want to include in our layout (the layout file does not need a `@model BaseModel` declaration)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so if I undertand you correctly, adding `@Html.Action("GetSideBar")`  in `_layout.cshtml` will call `<ACTIVE_CONTROLLER>.GetSideBar()`. In other words, I'd need to add the `GetSideBar()` action to all controllers, right?

Comment: You can just add it to one controller (say `HomeController`) and use `@Html.Action("GetSideBar", "Home")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm new to this, so please forgive me: you mean asp.net would still figure this out even if I'm accessing a different controller? In other words, if a user request `www.site.com/Schools/Index`, asp.net would still look for `HomeController.GetSideBar()` rather than `SchoolsController.GetSideBar()`?

Comment: Yes. The second parameter of `Action()` is the controller. (if you specify it, it will look for the method in that controller, but if you omit it, it will look for the method in the current controller)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I assume I can't just return a string, I'd need to create a model and a view for this particular `GetSideBar()` action and have it `return PartialView(SideBar_Model);`, is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126990/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-thedude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first that comes to mind for me is something static

```
public static class ServerWideData {
    private static Dictionary<string, Data> DataDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Data>();

    public static Data Get(string controllerName = "") { // Could optionally add a default with the area and controller name
        return DataDictionary[controllerName];
    }
    public static void Set(Data data, string name = "") {
        DataDictionary.Add(name, data);
    }

    public class Data {
        public string PropertyOne { get; set; } = "Value of PropertyOne!!";
        // Add anything here
    }
}
```

You can add data from anywhere by calling

```
    ServerWideData.Set(new Data() { PropertyOne = "Cheese" }, "Key for the data")
```

And retrieve it anywhere with

```
    ServerWideData.Get("Key for the data").PropertyOne // => Cheese
```

Comment: Very good idea. I'm going to try it, I'll get back to you with the results!